# How can I find my true vimrc file?

Tags: vimrc

I am a new to Vim and know little about programming.
The situation is this: I have both Vim and Gvim installed. From within Vim I think I have been able to use the `:e $MYVIMRC` command to do some edits I saw online. I was able to save it I think. I think so because the instructions I added show up when I open up Vim. 
However, now I want to also change the Vimrc for things related to my GVim (in particular I want to use GVim to to take advantage of python support). Here's where the weirdness happens for me. I try and use `:e $MYVIMRC` but when I open it up

- The vimrc file does not reflect any changes that I made from within Vim.
- The GVim program does not allow me to write to it.
  In fact, when I search for my vimrc file in my computer, I see only one file and it looks like the one that opens  up in GVim only.

I'd like to understand:

1. Why it appears I have to vimrc files though both programs echo back the same location
2. How I can make changes to the vimrc file from the vantage point of GVim.

I have searched the site but couldn't resolve it myself. Thank you for any help/tips.

Comment: You should be able to use the same file for both, but you can specify one to use for just gVim by naming it `.gvimrc`. Just to be clear: you've tried `:echo $MYVIMRC` in both Vim and gVim and they give the same result?

Comment: Hi Tumbler41. Yes when I echoed they both return the same place.

Comment: What's the location that's being reported for both?  Also, your post states you're using `:e $MYVIMRC$` (with a trailing `$`) but it should just be `:e $MYVIMRC`.

Comment: Ah, okay I edited that thanks. In both cases it said: C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc , but I did a broader search on the computer and now I saw there's some sort of ``virtual store'' which is still confusing to me, but at least I think this is getting at the issue?

Comment: As a side note, gVim (and I think vim as well) will need to be run as administrator to make changes to that location. I usually keep mine in `C:\Users\user\.vimrc` for that reason.

Comment: Thanks @Tumbler41. Does that  mean that to have the capabilities to make such changes I need to have my files in a user folder? In general should one copy all the vim folders to a user folder?

Comment: Don't bother copying all the vim files over. You only need to copy the `vimrc`.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's working and mostly making sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.vimrc` is sourced from both Vim & Gvim. This file will allow you to set up a common set of CLI & GUI plugins in a single location (shared by both the CLI Vim & Gvim)

The `.gvimrc` is used by Gvim only and will be sourced by Gvim only *after* the `.vimrc`. Regular command line Vim won't read from it.

Within Gvim, you can edit the `.vimrc` file if you want changes to appear to all instances of Vim, or if it's Gvim specific you should be able to edit the `.gvimrc` file separately (to change menus or whatever else the GUI allows you to change)

`:help gvimrc` should provide some more insight.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38353317/2892779

Answer (score 8):

The best way to find out, which files are loaded is to use the command
`:version`

You may also have secondary rc files, which are being sourced. They will be displayed here. You will also see, which version of vim you have.

In addition `:scriptnames` will list all scripts in the order they are loaded, this is probably not what you want and will also include plugin scripts, etc.

What strikes me as odd, is that on windows, you usually have a `_vimrc` or `_gvimrc` (_ instead of .) and the default directory for these is `%USERPROFILE%\vimfiles`